# Добавить к кнопке элемент после через :after

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Нужно сделать кнопку такого вида
[image]

**HTML**

```
<input name="" type="button" class="calculate-button-1 btn-2" value="Рассчитайте стоимость онлайн" />
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-2 {
    background: url(../images/bg_button_1.png) top left repeat;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    font-family: 'pt_sans_narrowbold';
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #2b2a29;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

.btn-2:after {
    content: url(../images/bg_button_after.png); 
}

.btn-2:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #9edcec;
}

.calculate-button-1 {
    width: 501px;
    height: 70px;
    margin-top: 55px;
    margin-left: 230px;
    padding-top: 2px !important;
}
```

Не получается добавить белый треугольник под кнопкой, пробую добавить его через псевдоэлемент `:after`, но ничего не отображается.

http://jsfiddle.net/j3bte/6/

Есть ли способ добавить этот элемент через псевдоэлемент `:after` или тут нужно использовать блок с абсолютным позиционированием?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:before` и `:after` добавляет контент к содержимому элемента, а у `input` же как такового содержимого нет.

Решение - завернуть инпуты в `div` и к нему уже применять псевдоэлементы.

или

использовать `button` так как это контейнер в отличии от `input`

```
http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/AAQth/
```

```css
input[type="submit"], input[type="button"] {
    outline: none;
}
.calculate-button-1 {
    width: 501px;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    padding-top: 2px !important;
}
.btn-2 {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/e0kwTeY.png) top left repeat;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    font-family:'pt_sans_narrowbold';
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #2b2a29;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-align: center;
}
.input-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.input-wrapper:after {
    content:'';
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/kzKwUd8.png) no-repeat;
    width: 34px;
    height: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -16px;
    left: 238px;
}
.btn-2:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #9edcec;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 300px; background-color: #ffcc33; padding-top: 10px;">
    <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input name="" type="button" class="calculate-button-1 btn-2" value="Рассчитайте стоимость онлайн" />
    </div>
</div>
```

также почитайте http://htmlbook.ru/blog/treugolniki-cherez-css

Comment: Мне нужно использовать `input`, а с `button` тоже получается немного не то http://jsfiddle.net/j3bte/7/

Comment: сделайте обертку div

Comment: а как запозиционировать элемент добавленный через `after` по центру блока? http://jsfiddle.net/j3bte/9/

Comment: в принципе, получилось запозиционировать через `margin-left: 462px;`, а какого способа просто задать для этого элемента расположение по центру нет?

Comment: сейчас в ответ добавлю

Comment: в принципе, задать расположение по центру получилось, если задать левое поле в процентах `.input-wrapper:after {
 content: url(../images/bg_button_after.png); 
 margin-left: 48%;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Все конечно отлично в ответе `soledar10`, но если изменится размер текста ваше выравнивание полетит. думаю стоит лучше сделать так:

```
.input-wrapper:after {
    content: '';
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/kzKwUd8.png) no-repeat;  
    width: 35px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100%; 
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-17px;     
}
```

как-то так)))

Comment: че-то я не пойму, какое увеличение какого текста может сбить выравнивание?